# Animation Nodes 2.1 strange bug

Tags: python, animation-nodes, error

If I try to insert **Mesh > Mesh from Object**, I see the following error:

[image]

This is Blender 2.79b and Animation Nodes 2.1.2. Strange thing is that this thing was working fine a couple of days ago when I started learning about Animation Nodes.

Things I have tried:

- Adding other nodes before adding **Mesh from Object**.
- Removing Animation Nodes addon and reinstalling.
- Removing the entire Animation Nodes folder from blender addons.
- Uninstalling and reinstalling Blender.

Looking at the bug text, however it appears to be a problem within the code. Anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: This node has been removed from Animation Nodes in newer version, and the developer forget to remove it from the menu hence the bug. You can get the same data from the *Mesh Object Input* node. If you get errors/bugs, report it to the developers directly. Like *[this](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/issues/914)*.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question appears to be about an issue caused by a bug in Animation Nodes. Which was reported [here](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/issues/914).